# Excel / VBA: How to set a conditional number formatting based on another cell value?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have an excel sheet that I am integrating some VBA code to it, but I am not been able to figure the following out.

On Cell G8 I have a drop-down list where I have the a description of the values on cells G9:G12, which are the following: Percentage, Discount, Premium. And on cells G9:G12 I have empty cells where I input my numbers.

Is it possible when I select for example, Percentage on cell G8, the number formating on cells G9:G12 change to "Percent"? And when I select Discount or Premium, the number formating changes to "Currency"?

Thank you!

Comment: Use a conditional formatting rule with a formula -> `=$G$8="Percentage"`, and another rule `=OR($G$8="Discount",$G$8="Premium")`.

Answer (score 0):

Although Bigben is close in this comment (using conditional formatting with a formula like `=$G$8="Percentage"`, it did not work in my case: I needed to put the value of the corresponding text ("Percentage"=1, "Discount"=2 and "Premium"=3), which changes the formula into:

```
=$G$8=1
```

Comment: Not sure why you can't get it to work, works fine for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxMR3.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFftH.png. I'm not just "close" :)

Comment: I'm working with excel 2013, that might explain it?

Comment: If that's it, it sounds like a bug, this is pretty simple as far as conditional formatting goes.

Comment: In any case, I'd propose not to close my answer, just in case other people might have the same issue.